# Implementing copy c'tor with shared pointer?

Tags: c++, class, methods, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Since my last question caused a lot of confusion I'm completely going to rewrite it with more info.

I have an **abstract** class `Character` which is being inherited by `Soldier` and `Medic`
I wrote another class called `Game` to manage a game board similar to chess game, it has the following objects:

```
    mtm::Dimensions dimensions;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> board;
```

Note previously I had `std::vector<Character*> board;` But was told by you that it's bad and I need to use smart pointers, while `unique_ptr` suits my code more but my professor wants me to use only `shared_ptr`.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the copy c'tor. I wrote:

```
Game::Game(const Game &other): dimensions(other.dimensions), board(dimensions.getRow()*dimensions.getCol()) {
    int board_size= dimensions.getRow()*dimensions.getCol();
    for (int i=0;i<board_size;++i)
    {
        this->board[i]=other.board[i];
    }
}
```

But it seems wrong and too much (as I was told by you). Any help?

Note: when I copy a game I don't want to have 2 games which share some pointers but spitted games so I could change one but not to affect the other.

Comment: Why do you calculate size when `other.board` has it?

Comment: @Slava what line are your referring to?

Comment: I am referring to `int board_size=...`, you get exactly the same value by `other.board.size()`

Comment: There is no function called size() @Slava

Comment: How about https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a copy of each `Character` object, for non abstract class without hierarchy this would be :

```
Game::Game(const Game &other): dimensions(other.dimensions) 
{
    board.reserve( other.board.size() );
    for( const auto &pch : other.board )
       board.push_back( std::make_shared( *pch ) );
}
```

assuming, that `Character` has proper copy ctor as well and it is not a pointer to base class which could be inherited.

In your case as it is abstract class and you point to derived ones you have to add pure virtual method `clone()` that returns `std::shared_ptr<Character>` to `Character` class and override it in every derived one:

```
class Character ... {
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Character> clone() const = 0;
    ...
};
```

Then `Game` copy ctor would be:

```
Game::Game(const Game &other): dimensions(other.dimensions) 
{
    board.reserve( other.board.size() );
    for( const auto &pch : other.board )
       board.push_back( pch->clone() );
}
```